# Multiple download request . from S3 signedUrl using Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created around 500 signed URLs of objects located in S3. Now when I try to download those objects from signed URL in a loop of

```
await Promise.all(signedUrls.map(async (url) => {
    const val = await request(url, (error, response) => {
        if (!error) {
            console.log('Downloaded successfully');
        } else {
            console.log('error in downloading', error.message);
        }
    });
}));
```

I get this error for some of the URLs.

> error in downloading getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND s3.amazonaws.com s3.amazonaws.com:443

I know all the signed URLs created are correct which I checked individually, but suspect that S3 there is an issue in downloading the files.

Need to check if there is any limit on S3 for requesting too many files.

Comment: `getaddrinfo()` failures can be domain name lookup failures. Try hardcoding the domain in `/etc/hosts` and see if it works. If it does, check your DNS server and consider using another one like `1.1.1.1` or `8.8.8.8` or `4.2.2.4`.

Answer (score 0):

S3 has no practical limit on the number of downloads or the number of concurrent downloads. In theory, there must be a limit because they have a finite amount of hardware in the AWS data centers, but that limit is so high that in practice you cannot reach it.

Comment: Im receiving now error message Not Found on one of the signed urls if I request 320 downloads through Promise.all. Strange thing if I send requests for download in batches it works.Something is wrong.

Comment: Are you using presigned urls? If so, check to make sure that they are not expiring.

Comment: They are not expiring as the same signed url that gives not found error in nodejs code works on the browser and downloads the file.

Comment: And above behaviour i see in 1 in 15 requests or so,